# How to create a web installer using codeigniter Php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to create a web installer,In other words i want whenever someone download our zip code
and extract then user should see a form ( register form) and after fill the form,data should save in database
How can i do this ?

Comment: so you expect people to also install a DB server? web server? and php?

Comment: @tim: i want something like plugin in wordpress ( but i want to integrate in php not wordpress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your folder structure there should be a **index.php** page and then when someone extract your file and try to access into it via **localhost it will open the index.php**. Then you should provide the sql file of the DB. Better to incliude a **readme** file. Where it will include that user have to extract your file and then need to upload sql file into db with the correct database name.

Comment: @anu if when you found a answer please mark it as a answer too

Comment: you mean i just need two files ( index.php and sql file ), right ?

Comment: @Anu yes but user should have to install wamp or samp or something like that and they should have a knowledge to extract your file at **www** folder or something similar to that with respect to localhost they use